# How to let vite write an map object to a json file

Tags: typescript, vite

I am using Vite, and I have a ts file that exports an object. I want to write this object to a file (like public/output.json) when dev | build starts.

How can I do this?

Comment: import module from vite.config.ts it will run as nodejs

Comment: @TachibanaShin do you mean import the object, and use fs to write to dist/output.json? first, i thought vite may has an effect way to do this, second, the object file has a lot of depencies, so i need to update vite's ts config to include a lot of dependencies.

Comment: none of the data you provided says more about that please clarify the question. except for `ssr` and `csr plugin` vite there is no mechanism that allows you to do this